# How to call value of selected List from Jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I want  to call the value of selected li with jquery . Here is my ul list,get data from Database and

```
<ul id="scroller1">
    <?php       
        $globalregion_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM GlobalRegion");
        $i = 0;
        while($globalregion_row = mysql_fetch_array($globalregion_result)){
            echo "<li id='scroller1_" . $i . "' value='" . $globalregion_row["GlobalRegionID"]  . "'>" . $globalregion_row["GlobalRegionName"] . "</li>";
            $i++;
        }                                   

    ?>
</ul>
```

Here is my jquery call for list

```
var scroll1SCell = null;
var scroll1SVal =  $("#scroller1 .active-item").attr("value");
```

It show "undefined" at console.

Comment: `ul`'s don't have a "value." Do you mean to use a `<select>`'s value (the selected `<option>`)?

Comment: yes,I am using li for multiple listed. scroller1,2,3.Scroller2 li data will be based on scroller1 selected.same Scroller3 data will be based on scroller1,2 selected. My idea of call list value is to show user the value of "Selected List"

Answer (score 0):

The `li`'s id is something like: `id='scroller1_" . $i . "'`. Which means you'll have to use that specific selector to find the element:

```
var index = // get the index of the li you need.
$("#scroller1_"+index).attr("value");
```

As @rgthree pointed out you're using `li`'s incorrectly. These elements are meant to just be lists of text or other elements, but not select boxes. The `value` attribute is not a valid attribute. Instead you might want to use this code:

HTML:

```
<select id="scroller1">
    <?php       

    $globalregion_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM GlobalRegion");
    $i = 0;
    while($globalregion_row = mysql_fetch_array($globalregion_result)){
    echo "<option value='" . $globalregion_row["GlobalRegionID"]  . "'>" . $globalregion_row["GlobalRegionName"] . "</option>";
    $i++;
    }                                   

    ?>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var value = $("#scroller1").val();
```

Comment: yes,I am using li for multiple listed. scroller1,2,3.Scroller2 li data will be based on scroller1 selected.same Scroller3 data will be based on scroller1,2 selected. My idea of call list value is to show user the value of "Selected List".

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

$("#scroller1").val();

Answer (score 0):

var scroll1SVal =  $("#scroller1 option:selected").val();